# How to link libraries in cmake

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, cmake, glfw

I am trying to pass my c++ project that I was developing in Linux to windows.

I am using cLion so a cMake.

this is my Cmake

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10) # common to every CLion project
    project(PackMan) # project name


    set(GLM_DIR C:/libs/GLM/glm)
    set(GLAD_DIR C:/libs/GLAD/include)

    include_directories(${GLM_DIR})
    include_directories(${GLAD_DIR})

    find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
    pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw)

    ADD_LIBRARY(mainScr
            scr/Carte.cpp
            scr/Enemy.cpp
            scr/MoveableSquare.cpp
            scr/Palette.cpp
            scr/Player.cpp
            scr/Square.cpp
            scr/Wall.cpp
            scr/glad.c
    )


    add_executable(PackMan scr/main.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(PackMan libglfw3.a)
    target_link_libraries(PackMan mainScr)
```

Every include folder works fine.

I copie pasted dll file ro systeme32 folder inside windows folder.
So like I said in my project I have all external includes i can see where the definition is made and everything but it seems like I cant link them with dll.

I get the error of

```
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw'
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2022.1.1/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:890 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (pkg_search_module)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/tanku/Documents/Projects/PackMan/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

when I try to build.

Comment: Plese, show **exact error message** (not a pattern "everything related to glfw"). This error message should also contain a name of the source or object file, which calls undefined function. According to that file we could determine, which **target** - executable or a library - causes the error.

Comment: I edited my post for more informations

Comment: `lib-vc2022` tells that you have a lib built for MSVC and `C:\MinGW\bin\c++.exe` tells that you use not an MSVC compiler. So you get what is expected. Your CMake isn't incorrect but your libraries are. You need to get correct libs and you will be fine.

Comment: I changed my libraries to lib-mingw-w64 but I still have the same problem. At the end of cMake now I do target_link_libraries(PackMan mainScr libglfw3.a libglfw3dll.a) and I changed the dll file inside systeme32 with the new dll (I have no idea if I should but did it anyways)

Comment: Don't post your updates in the comment section, update your post with the changes and errors you have after you applied them.

Comment: editted with regarding the only answer and your comment with the new error

Comment: If you are using mingw I recommend using msys2 to provide your mingw and use its package management pacman to install your libraries. I suspect you don't have the proper binaries for mingw. The command to install the x64 glfw binaries for mingw is `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw` here: [https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw](https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-glfw) looking at the files there is direct cmake support in the files provided in this binary package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing that wrong way. You should use `find_package` instead hard-coding paths.

This should go more or less like this:

```
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)

add_library(mainScr
        scr/Carte.cpp
        scr/Enemy.cpp
        scr/MoveableSquare.cpp
        scr/Palette.cpp
        scr/Player.cpp
        scr/Square.cpp
        scr/Wall.cpp
        scr/glad.c)

target_link_libraries(mainScr PUBLIC ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(mainScr PUBLIC ${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(PackMan scr/main.cpp)
```

This should work if GLFW is properly installed. On Windows you can use vcpkg to manage c++ libraries.

This is done based on [GLFW documentation](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html#build_link_cmake_pkgconfig) - didn't test this.

Comment: I tried this but does not work editted the new error with the cMake that I changed pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3) does not work eighter

Comment: `On Windows you can use vcpkg to manage c++ libraries.`

Comment: not vcpkg but another package manager helped me, suggested by @drescherjm: I installed MSYS2 and changed my toolset (settings -> toolchains) to msys2's mingw64 and now I can find packages that I installed with msys2. Thanks a lot!